# Logging SFTP activity with auditd

Tags: logging, sftp, auditd

I am currently using auditd to log TTY activity for users that are SSH'd into my system. However, SFTP sessions are not logged in this way. Is there a way to log them using auditd or will I need to use a separate logger for SFTP?

Answer (score 1):

You can log SFTP sessions / activity (example below), but the log messages will be written to /var/log/messages.

I don't know if you can configure **auditd** to "scan" the /var/log/messages file after that, but here it goes:

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_conf

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Change this to 
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -f AUTH -l INFO

service sshd restart
```

INFO logging level provides detailed information regarding file transfers, permission changes, etc. 
If you need more info, you can use:
QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO, VERBOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2, and DEBUG3

Comment: I've found the logging from SFTP to be a little lackluster but if this is the best way I'll work with it.